# What size wire do I use? BLDC Motor

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I'm currently doing a project that requires two brushless outrunner motors to power it. As I plan on running it off 24v, and have space and weight requirements that mean I can't use a gearbox (instead I'll be using a chain and sprocket to gear it down), I need it to run at about 3000rpm max.

Usually, I'd either buy a stock motor and run it as is from the factory or rewind it to lower kv when that is an issue for me. Alas, I cannot seem to find a motor suitable enough for either thing so I've elected to build my own (I can find motors that fit one of my three requirements, but none can do two or three).

After quite a bit of research I think the 5065 motor will be the best size for me, with a 14 pole 12 stator pole configuration. To get my desired power/kv, what is the formula I need to use in order to work out the wire thickness I need?

Answer (score 0):

The speed constant Kv is determined by the strength of the magnets and the number of turns in your coils.

The back-EMF voltage can be calculated from [Faraday's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction):

$$\mathcal{E} = -N \frac{\mathrm{d}\Phi_B}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

Here dt will be the time it takes for a magnetic pole to pass over the stator pole, and dϕ<sub>B</sub> is the change of magnetic flux (weber). The magnetic flux will depend on magnet type and it's cross sectional area.

The cheapest N35 grade neodymium magnets have field strength of about 1 tesla.  If the rotor permanent magnet has cross-section of e.g. 100 mm², this gives 0.1 mWb flux. When north and south poles alternate, the change will be twice this. If your stator coil then has 100 turns, this would give back-EMF voltage of 1 V when dt is 20 ms. For 14 rotor poles, this gives 280 ms per rotation, which equals 214 RPM. Thus the motor would have Kv of 214.

Increasing the number of turns in coil will increase back-EMF voltage, making the motor spin slower at given voltage and reduce the Kv constant.

The maximum motor current is primarily determined by the resistive losses in the coils. Therefore you want to use as thick wire as you can fit in the stator.

The motor voltage is only limited by insulation strength and power supply. The highest output power for BLDC motors is always obtained at the highest RPM, because the maximum current and torque is relatively constant across the speed range.

I would suggest the following order of design steps:

1. Determine the field strength of your rotor + stator combination. You can either calculate with equation above, or wrap a test coil and measure the output voltage when you spin the motor externally at constant RPM.
2. Select the number of turns to reach your desired Kv. With the 24 V power supply, I would suggest designing the motor to run at target RPM with e.g. 12 V motor voltage. This gives some margin for losses in the circuit, and the motor controller will be able to efficiently chop down the voltage.
3. Measure available space for the coil, and calculate what is the thickest wire you can fit the necessary number of turns in the space.